# Comparative clause

Tags: comparative-constructions

I was watching a movie where The main character said to his friend

"**I am disturbed to find that I had more of a childhood than you did**."

Why he said 'you did' after 'than' normally we use 'You had'? Is It an archaic form to use as the movie storyline was based on very old time?

Answer (score 1):

I expect your confusion comes from the fact that you have not realised that *have* here is not an auxiliary. In this sentence *had* is the past form of the verb [*have*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have#have__20). When using an  ordinary verb, we make questions, negatives, restatement of the verb in comparatives, using an auxiliary. In your sentence *had* being in the past, we have to use the auxiliary *did*.

Your sentence follows the same construction as, for example, *I ate more cakes than you did* in which *did* restates *ate*.

If the sentence had been written in the present perfect your sentence would have been:

> I've had more of a childhood than you have.
> (have: *auxiliary*; *had* main verb).

Future:

> He'll have more of a childhood than you will.
> (will: *auxiliary*; *have* main verb).

In the same way you will find sentences such as:

> What time do you have breakfast?

> I don't have a pet.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite idiomatic.

"I *had*" is basically the same as saying "I *did have*".

> "I had one, and so did you".